# LTRIM RTRIM not working for Chinese string SQL

Tags: sql

I have a column named Text which receives from the end user the following string:

`'复合模头滤网　φ245　120目*300目 24×120目　'`

Which includes a weird space, kind of larger than the regular space, at the end. However it has the same ASCII code as the normal space 32.

I used this SQL code to trim my string but always returning same string without trimming !!!!

```sql
LTRIM(RTRIM([Text]))
```

Comment: I've removed the tag spam here. Please tag correctly, and only tag what you're *really* using.

Comment: Apparently this is a `U+3000 : IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE` which SQL Server doesn't identify as whitespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to try trim the the character with the ASCII code 32. The following code works perfectly:

```sql
TRIM(CHAR(32) from [ShortText])
```

To check it out if works , I tried it this way :

```sql
DECLARE @t TABLE(txt nvarchar(255));
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (TRIM(CHAR(32) from '复合模头滤网　φ245　120目*300目 24×120目　'));

SELECT txt, LEN((txt)), ASCII(RIGHT(txt,1)) AS ASCII_Char
--32=SPACE,--13 CR,--11 LF, 9-tab
FROM @t
```

Comment: Using a `varchar` literal here is most certainly going to result in data loss.

Comment: What do you mean, I didn't get it ? the solution I did going to result a data loss ?

Comment: The above will result in the value `N'?????? f245 120?*300? 24×120?'`.

Comment: the second part of the answer just to check if the space at the end was trimmed or not. Which it did , as you can see no space at the end of the string you posted. About the result with ????, it is normal SSMS results doesn't interpret Chinese characters the right way. However, in my database I'm having now the exact right string without the weird space at the end.

Comment: *"About the result with ????, it is normal SSMS results doesn't interpret Chinese characters the right way"* This is not true at all. And I didn't even run the above in SSMS. [But this is what an `nvarchar` with your value looks like in SSMS.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAZIb.png) The reason the characters have been lost is, as I stated, due to your choice of using a literal `varchar`, not a literal `nvarchar`.

Comment: Well, as I said for the second part of answer I just wanted to check if it works. However, What solved my problem is just this `TRIM(CHAR(32) from [ShortText])`

Answer (score 0):

**This character is `U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE`**, and [as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), SQL Server by default only removes `U+0020 SPACE`.

You can use `TRIM(... FROM` in modern versions of SQL Server

```sql
DECLARE @t nvarchar(1000) = N'复合模头滤网　φ245　120目*300目 24×120目　';

SELECT
  DATALENGTH(@t) / 2 totalCharacters,
  LEN(@t) totalCharactersTrimmed,
  TRIM(@t) trimmedNormal,
  DATALENGTH(TRIM(@t)) / 2 totaTrimmedNormal,
  TRIM(NCHAR(0x3000) FROM @t) trimmedIdeographic,
  TRIM(N'　' FROM @t) trimmedIdeographic,
  DATALENGTH(TRIM(NCHAR(0x3000) FROM @t)) / 2 totalTrimmedIdeographic;
  
SELECT
  UNICODE(NCHAR(0x3000)) unicodeNum,
  ASCII(NCHAR(0x3000)) asciiNum;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7b545f159384884410468003b41c0571)

You claim it has the same ASCII code, however that is just because ASCII does not have an exact character for it. If you use the `UNICODE` function, you will see the difference, as the fiddle shows.

For such characters as these, you must make sure to use the `nvarchar` data type, and the `NCHAR` and `UNICODE` functions.